# C++ Compare 2 Floats to another float

Tags: c++, math

I have the following question.  Let's say I've got 3 float values:

```
float1 = 300.00;
float2 = 200.00;
float3 = 100.00;
```

Now I want to determine which of the two floats (float2 & float3) is closer to float1 and then return a true or false.

```
if closercheck(float1, float2, float3) //Example Code
{
    console.write("float2 is nearer to float1");
}
else
{
    console.write("float3 is nearer to float1");
}
```

So the output would be:

> float 2 is nearer to float 1

Now my question is, how could I code the "closercheck()" function?

I know how to check which of the 2 floats is closer to zero: `(abs(float2) < abs(float3))`.

But I don't know how to compare 2 floats to another float.

Comment: how would you do it if i was to ask you in conversation to do it, write that out in code - ie "Which of these 2 numbers is closer to 42, 9 or 498?"

Comment: There may be several solutions, but couldn' t you simply subtract each one of them (float2 and float 3) with the first one, and then compare the results?

Comment: @pm100 i could subtract float 1 with 2 and float 1 with 3 and see which one gives the bigger sum, but this is a bit difficult if the float values can also be minus.

Comment: Do you care about edge cases like `float1 = FLT_MIN; float2 = 1.0f; float3 = 2.0f;`?

Comment: @Artyer we can use integers instead if needed

Comment: if `abs(float2 - float1)` is smaller (<) than `abs(float3-float1)`, then float2 is closer to float1.

Comment: First step is to define a few test cases, i.e. inputs and expected results. Then, just start writing the code (try something) and adjust it until every test case gives the expected results. Concerning "I don't know how to compare 2 floats to another float", you just write a function for that as you laid out already. How to implement it, you have already presented that info above, so it's unclear what is unclear to you. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @YuutaCoding still works with negative numbers - try it

Comment: What is `console.write`?

Comment: Which do you want to return if the floats are equidistant? (And that's a weaker condition than float2 == float3.) Another consideration is that if float2 is -Inf say and float3 is +Inf then perhaps float2 is closer if float1 is non-positive? And how do you want to handle the NaN?

Answer (score -4):

First decide on the precision(n) of the answer and then use %.nf to get a final value of the operands. The difference in subtraction results should be able to get you the correct result(even for negative values).

Comment: What is “%.nf”? And why would a precision have to be decided on?

Comment: I used n to symbolize the value of precision its value could be 1,2,3.. depending on the precision expected in the code. Precision implies number of decimal digits after the dot. I think it is necessary since the question deals with calculating difference in floating numbers.

Comment: Adding an example: 
98.4444 and 101.5556 are equidistant from 100.0000 if the precision value i.e 'n' is 4 but if there is a 5th precision digit that could very well decide which float is closer to 100.00000. If it is clear what I meant, can I have my 2 reputation back ?? :)

Comment: The question is about deciding which floats are closer to another float. Your answer seems to be about printing floats, something which was not asked about. However, if you could clarify with a small code sample that might help.

Comment: Why would decimal digits be involved? Given that it’s possible to calculate the answer precisely, why would you want to try to be imprecise?

Comment: @President James K. Polk the format specifier could be used inside an sprintf/snprintf and then combined with atof/strtof.

Comment: @Sneftel that is something to ponder over and should come from design perspective. I have rarely seen float values being used without a precision of decimal places. A simple example would be an a2d converter where the analog decimal values are truncated before levels are decided upon. I added something extra but nothing incorrect to my answer. It is quite obvious that calculating differences should fetch us the expected results.